# How to webscrape this website

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

I have a website here

[BSE SmallCap](http://money.rediff.com/indices/bse/bsesmallcap)

About 100 companies are listed here.
How can I save the next 100 companies programmatically using Python(or C#).
On the bottom of this page

> Showing 1 - 100 of 528    << Previous | Next >>

is seen.How can I access the link

> Next >>

programmatically.This link is seen as base url + '#'(http://money.rediff.com/indices/bse/bsesmallcap#).
How to save all the 1-528 company details(as seperate webpages:1-100,101-200 etc).
Is there any special tailormade programs for these kind of tasks.

Comment: you might want to make your question more specific if you're looking for a good answer - this is something google can definitely help solve. Also, check out scrapy or BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need scrapy or anything like that--there's no link to find with that "Next" link, since it's actually javascript:

```
javascript:nextPage(document.paging.totalPages.value)
```

I used Chrome's developer tools to see what request it was actually making, and it turns out it's just a simple unauthenticated POST request.  You can get any page you want with the following:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://money.rediff.com/indices/bse/bsesmallcap',
              data={'currentPageNo': 3, 'RowPerPage': 100})
print r.text
```

All you have to do is change the `'currentPageNo'` argument to get whichever page you're looking for.  <strike>You could probably also change the number of rows per page, but I didn't experiment with that.</strike>  *Update: You can't;  I tried.*

In terms of actually saving the information, you can use `BeautifulSoup` to grab the data from each request and store it or save it.  Given that the table regularly has the `'dataTable'` class on each page, it's pretty easy to find.  So, given that there are 6 pages, you'd end up with code that looks something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
for page in range(1, 7):
    r = requests.post('http://money.rediff.com/indices/bse/bsesmallcap',
                      data={'currentPageNo': page, 'RowPerPage': 100})
    soup = BS(r.text)
    table = soup.find(class_='dataTable')
    # Add table information to whatever output you plan to use
```

Answer (score 2):

The full link to "each page" is:
    http://money.rediff.com/indices/bse/bsesmallcap&cTab=12&sortBy=&sortDesc=&pageType=indices_wise&currentPageNo=1&RowPerPage=100&bTab=12

(I've removed the totalPages aspect, since you'll need to scrape this bit yourself)

Once you know the number of pages (from scraping), you can increment the `currentPageNo` until you have all the rows.

You can increase the number of RowsPerPage, but there seems to be an internal limit of 200 rows (even if you change it to say, 500)

Comment: How did you get this whole link?

Comment: @Vinod That was achieved using Google Chrome's developer tools (Network tab)

Answer (score 1):

A spin on [jdotjdot's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351335/jdotjdot) answer using [`PyQuery`](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/) instead of [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), I like it for the jQuery-esque notation for traversing. It will use `urllib` by default or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for scraping.

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
for page in range(1, 3):
    # POST request
    d = pq(url="http://money.rediff.com/indices/bse/bsesmallcap",
           data={"currentPageNo": page, "RowPerPage": 50},
           method="post")
    # jQuery-esque notation for selecting elements
    d("table.dataTable").text()
```

Comment: Tried to install Pyquery.It is asking for lxml.

Comment: @Vinod Are you opposed to installing `lxml`?

Comment: @beargle I'm opposed to installing `lxml`; always have problems with it on Windows.

Comment: @jdotjdot I've used the unofficial binaries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) without any trouble. Both parsing solutions work, just a matter of preference I guess :-)

Comment: @beargle Can I get this table as a list of rows.

Comment: @Vinod Take a look at the [.items()](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/api.html#pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery.items) method. Post another question with expected output if you have trouble.